# CMake copy files using copy_if_different recursively

Tags: cmake

I am new to CMake. I have got my project compiling. I have a structure like this

PROJECT

- SRC

  1. test
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt for this folder (creating a static library)
  2. example
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt for this folder (creating a static library)
- Include

  1. test
     .h (all the header files)
  2. example
     .h (all the header files)
- build

  1. CMakeLists.txt (Main CMakelist file)
- lib

  1. test  (contains the generated files)
  2. example  (contains the generated files)

The question is how do I copy all static files ie. from test and example folder and place them in a different folder outside the binary structure recursively?

My main CMakeLists.txt file:

```
PROJECT(copythefiles)

SET(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ".")

add_subdirectory(/src/test /lib/test) # I am specifying the location where the files are to be generated
add_subdirectory(/src/example /lib/example)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( a ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "\{X}" > ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/test/libtest.a )

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET a POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/test/libtest.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libtest.a )
```

This copies the files. But I have around 20 projects and I would like to do it recursively.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal to have your top-level CMakeLists.txt file in the root of your project.  If you move your CMakeLists.txt out of "/build" to the root, then you should be able to call `add_subdirectory` without having to specify the binary path for each case.

Assuming you move the CMakeLists file, then you can insert this before the `add_subdirectory` calls:

```
function(MoveLib TheTarget)
  add_custom_command(TARGET ${TheTarget} POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
                         copy $<TARGET_FILE:${TheTarget}> ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
endfunction()

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

This then allows you to add e.g. `MoveLib(my_test)` inside the libraries' CMakeLists.txt files, where `my_test` is the name of the library concerned.

A copy of all libraries will then end up in "/lib".  If you're not really wanting copies, then you should have a look at the [`ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) property.  If you simply add

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

then all your static libraries will end up in "/lib".  There are a couple of things to watch for here though.

Shared libraries aren't covered by `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`.  The details for shared libs are in the docs for `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` though.

Also, some generators (e.g. MSVC) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory, so you'd end up with "/lib/Debug", "/lib/Release", etc.  You can circumvent this by setting the configuration-specific versions of `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to all point to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib`:

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```